# Creating tables error and create multiple tables using codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, mariadb

i've been meaning to insert data to an existing table and create table automaticaly when someone sign up but i have some problems.

this is my form_reg

```
<div class="row">   
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST" action="<?php echo base_url()?>index.php/tr/reg">
                <table style="width:110%" class="table table-striped table table-bordered table table-hover">
                    <tr>
                        <td>Nama Lengkap</td>
                        <td><input class="form-control" type="text" name="nama"/></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Username</td>
                        <td><input class="form-control" type="text" name="username"/></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Password</td>
                        <td><input class="form-control" type="password" name="password"/></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Nomor TBS</td>
                        <td><input class="form-control" type="number" name="no_tbs"/></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>Program</td>
                        <td><input class="form-control" type="text" name="program"/></td>
                    </tr>
            
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td><button class="btn btn-info" type="submit" name="btnsubmit" value="Simpan">Register</button>
                        
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
```

and this my controller named tr.php

```
public function reg(){ 
    $posts_fields=array(
    'id'=>array('type' => 'INT','constraint' => 11,'unsigned' => TRUE,'auto increment' => TRUE,'primary key' => TRUE),
    'tanggal'=>array('type' =>'DATE','constraint' => 100),
    'tbs_terhadap'=>array('type'=>'number','constraint' => 100),
    'keterangan'=>array('type'=>'text','constraint' => 100),
    'masuk'=>array('type'=>'number','constraint' => 100),
    'keluar'=>array('type'=>'number','constraint' => 100),
    'saldo_dsp'=>array('type'=>'number','constraint' => 100),
    'tbs_id'=>array('type'=>'INT','constraint'=>11));

for($i = 1; $i <= 100000; $i++) {
   $formattedNumber = sprintf('%05d', $i);
   echo "<tr><td>$formattedNumber</td></tr>";


$this->dbforge->add_field($posts_fields);
$this->dbforge->create_table('dsp');
    

    $nama = $_POST['nama'];
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $no_tbs = $_POST['no_tbs'];
    $program = $_POST['program'];

        $data_insert = array(
            'nama' => $nama,
            'username' => $username,
            'password' => $password,
            'no_tbs' => $no_tbs,
            'program' => $program,
            
        );
        
        $res = $this->mymodel->RegData('tbs_member', $data_insert);
    
    
    if($res >= 1 && $result!==false){
        $this->session->set_flashdata('pesan','Register Success');
        header("location: /tbs/index.php/web?gagal=0&sukses=1");
    }else{
        header("location: /tbs/index.php/web/register?gagal=1");
    }
}
```

and this is mymodel.php

```
public function RegData($tableName, $data)
{
    $res = $this->db->insert($tableName, $data);
    return $res;
}
```

**UPDATE**: After i use the `$this->load->dbforge()`, the problems changed and this is what came out after i run it

> A Database Error Occurred
>
> Error Number: 1064
>
> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '(100) NULL, `tbs_terhadap` VARCHAR(100) NULL, `keterangan` VARCHAR(100) NU' at line 3
>
> CREATE TABLE `dsp$formattedNumber` ( `id` INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, `tanggal` DATE(100) NULL, `tbs_terhadap` VARCHAR(100) NULL, `keterangan` VARCHAR(100) NULL, `masuk` VARCHAR(100) NULL, `keluar` VARCHAR(100) NULL, `saldo_dsp` VARCHAR(100) NULL, `tbs_id` INT(11) NOT NULL, CONSTRAINT `pk_dsp$formattedNumber` PRIMARY KEY(`id`) ) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8 COLLATE = utf8_general_ci
>
> Filename: C:/xampp/htdocs/genstore/tbs/system/database/DB_driver.php
>
> Line Number: 691

and also i need info if it's posible to create multiple tables at once? and if it is please tell me how

that is all i need to ask.. just tell me if there's any information that i left out.. i am kinda new in this please tell me what's my mistake is? thanks

Comment: I answered to your error. If you ask many things at once, it'll be too broad. Once you get one thing solved, check your other problems (maybe there are answers already). Also, changed mysql tag to mariadb as your error log says you're using MariaDB.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you can set a DATE(100) field? It seems to me that your query is failing because of that (you don't need to specify length for a DATE field)

```
CREATE TABLE dsp$formattedNumber ( 
id INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
tanggal DATE NULL, 
tbs_terhadap VARCHAR(100) NULL, 
keterangan VARCHAR(100) NULL, 
masuk VARCHAR(100) NULL, 
keluar VARCHAR(100) NULL, 
saldo_dsp VARCHAR(100) NULL, 
tbs_id INT(11) NOT NULL, 
CONSTRAINT pk_dsp$formattedNumber PRIMARY KEY(id) ) 
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8 COLLATE = utf8_general_ci;
```